# how to return variables from inside image onLoad

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, observable, onload

```
  export class AttachmentComponent {
   imageWidth: number;
   imageHeight: number;
   ngOnInit() {
    this.imgSize(imagePath);
   }
   getImageSize(url) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = imgurl;
    img.onload = (event) => {
      const  loadedImage: any = event.currentTarget;
      const width = loadedImage.width;
      const height = loadedImage.height;
    }
   }
 }
```

Here I want to populate 'imageWidth' and 'imageHeight' properties of the class with the width and height being calculated inside the onLoad in the getImageSize. help?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your problem is correct, you want to assign value of **loadedImage.width** to **imageWidth** property and the same with **height**.

You are able to do that by referencing to **this** which is **AttachmentComponent** instance.

```
export class AttachmentComponent {
   imageWidth: number;
   imageHeight: number;
   ngOnInit() {
    this.imgSize(imagePath);
   }
   getImageSize(url) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = imgurl;
    img.onload = (event) => {
      const  loadedImage: any = event.currentTarget;
      // => here is what I've changed
      this.imageWidth = loadedImage.width;
      this.imageHeight = loadedImage.height;
    }
   }
 }
```